How to add a middleware before the application starts up in FastAPI?
Using Lifespan Events and Middleware, I would like to add a middleware inside an asynccontextmanager, at application startup. It should look something like this:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    if some_condition:
        @app.middleware("http")
        async def my_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
            response = await call_next(request)
            return response
    yield
    pass


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

However, the example above raises the following error:
RuntimeError: Cannot add middleware after an application has started

But, in the beginning of Lifespan Events documentation, it is mentioned that:

You can define logic (code) that should be executed before the
application starts up. This means that this code will be executed
once, before the application starts receiving requests.

How should I approach this?

Why would you want to add a middleware in a startup handler? Jyst add it as normal, with the same conditional?

For setup/install (database and etc) purposes. I want to redirect all routes to /setup if the configuration file does not exist.

The Lifespan events will be executed before even the application starts handling the requests. During the execution of lifespan, the application didn't start listening. Only after the execution of Lifespan the application starts handling requests. If you want to setup the database do it in the Lifespan. If you want to redirect users to /setup page, then use the middleware separately to do the things.

Would a custom base API Route class work better? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router

What is described and demonstrated in your question, i.e., adding a middleware inside the lifespan handler is not possible. As the error you get says, you "cannot add middleware after an application has started". You could, however, use the following approach instead.
First, you could add arbitrary objects/variables, such as some_condition attribute in your example, to the state inside the lifespan handler at application startup, as demonstrated in this answer and this answer. For example:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Run at startup
    some_condition = ...
    yield {'some_condition': some_condition}
    # Run on shutdown

Second, you would define your http middleware as usual—see this answer for examples—in which you would access the some_condition attribute from request.state, and finally, perform the required validation check you need inside the middleware instead. For instance:
from fastapi import Request

@app.middleware("http")
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    if request.some_condition:
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
    else:
        pass

To redirect all routes to a specific one, as you mentioned in a comment earlier, you might want to have a look at this answer, as well as this answer and this answer.
